# Java - Why does GC times increase as heap grows (in terms of capacity)?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

At least in old GCs, it holds true. (I know there are new ones like ZGC and Shenandoah that aim to eliminate that)

As far as I know GC keeps tracks of living objects, so shouldn't the GC times be mostly affected by the number of objects (living/needs to be cleared)?

**EDIT:**
I meant grows in terms of capacity, meaning bigger heap but same utilization of it by the application

Comment: Do you have any statistics, benchmarks, links or whatever additional information that your question is based on? I assume that you mean by *"heap grows"* increased capacity.

Comment: Yes about the "heap grows" (edited), I dont have any benchmarks or anything but its something thats known

Comment: I doubt that this is just *known*. How the garbage collector works and so on is already pretty advanced stuff. Anyways, feel free to post some links or whatever about exact that problem. I found [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/factors-affecting-garbage-collection-performance.htm#JSGCT-GUID-5508674B-F32D-4B02-9002-D0D8C7CDDC75), may it be relevant for your question ...

Comment: The key point is to understand the difference between “overall time spent in GC” and “maximum pause time”.

Comment: @akuzminykh Then how do you explain the fact that one of the core properties of both ZGC and Shendonanah GC is that "Pause times do not increase with the heap or live-set size"?

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you answer your own question?

> As far as I know GC keeps tracks of living objects, so shouldn't the GC times be mostly affected by the number of objects (living/needs to be cleared)?

The more the heap grows, the more live objects it has, the slower the GC (I'm sure there are exceptions to this rule, in particular for minor collections, but that's the rough idea). The number of objects to be cleared is irrelevant, what matters most is the total number of live objects. Now if your heap is growing because you're storing long-lived objects, it might be ok as long as you don't keep on adding more and more of them. Eventually, long-lived objects will move towards the survivor space and will only be subject to major collections and not minor ones. As long as the minor GC always achieve sufficient memory freeing from the young generation, major GC won't be triggered on all objects (which includes long-lived ones).

I have also observed a different behaviour with G1. We had a low-latency application (40ms p99), so we attempted to configure G1 to make very short pauses (can't remember how much, maybe 5ms or so). What happened is that G1 was more or less meeting the 5ms target, but it had to run extremely frequently because 5ms was not enough to cope with all dead objects we had in our heap. Therefore, it's not exactly true to say individual garbage collection runs are going to get slower with increased heap size, however the average time spent in garbage collection in a given period of time is most likely going to increase.

Comment: I edited my question, sorry for not being clear, I meant grows in terms of capacity

Comment: Ah ok, well I don't think this would necessarily get slower then, especially because modern garbage collectors all subdivide the memory in logical spaces, so they know where the garbage is and then don't randomly look at places where there's nothing. However, why would one want a larger heap is they're not also using more memory? The two are correlated.

Comment: Its really more of a theoretical problem.
I was reading about GC and noticed this and could explain to myself why that makes sense.
Though for example, you could have an app that uses a small number of very large objects, so you'll need a bigger heap and GC times would slow down but it wont be because of the number of living objects since you have very little and im trying to understand what is it about the GC algorithm that would cause this.

Comment: I have to agree with @akuzminyk at this point, where from do you get the fact that GC will go slower on a large heap with a small number of objects?

Comment: @tomer.z Objects gets moved in memory in order to avoid fragmentation, and this overhead is proportional to the heap size. However, heap compacting doesn't get done by all GCs every time....

Comment: @Dici I saw it in a couple of places (dont have links right now) and "extrapolated" that from the fact that one of the core properties of both ZGC and Shendonanah GC is that "Pause times do not increase with the heap or live-set size"?

Comment: It's incorrect to say, "Eventually, long-lived objects will move towards the survivor space..."  Objects are copied to a survivor space during their *first* minor GC. Objects will be copied between survivor spaces until they reach the tenuring threshold and are promoted to the old generation.

Comment: Mm true, I mixed up the name of the different generations and spaces. Thanks :p

Answer (score 0):

There are many different algorithms that can be used to implement garbage collection.  Not all of them exhibit the behaviour you mention.

In the case of your question, you are referring to algorithms that use a form of mark-sweep.  If we take the HostSpot JVM as an example, the old generation can be collected using the CMS collector.  This uses a marking phase, where all objects that are accessible from application code are marked.  Initially, a root set of directly accessible objects (object references on the stack, registers, etc.) is created.  Each object in this set has the mark-bit set in its header to indicate it is still in use.  All references from these objects are recursively followed and ulitmately every accessible object has the mark-bit set.  How long this takes is proportional to the number of live objects, not the size of the heap.

The sweeping phase then has to sweep throught the entire heap, looking for objects with the mark-bit set and determining the gaps between them so that they can be added to free lists.  These are used to allocate space for objects being promoted from the young generation.  Since the whole heap must be swept, the time this takes *is* proportional to the size of the heap, regardless of how much live data is in the heap.

In the case of G1, the algorithm is similar but each generation of the heap is divided into regions so that space can be reclaimed in a more efficent way.